# C++ nested templates return type

Tags: c++, class, templates, nested

i'm trying to return a nested template object from its template container class

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    template <typename S>
    struct node {
        S value;
        struct node<S>* right;
        ....
    };
    private:
        ....
        node<T>* foo();
}
```

i'm having then

```
template <typename T>
A<T>::node<T>* A<T>::foo() {
....
}
```

this is the visual studio's errors

```
1>  A.cpp
1>c:\users\user\dropbox\visual studio projects\fooProj\fooProj\A.cpp(576): warning C4346: 'A<T>::?$node@$RT@BAAB@' : dependent name is not a type
1>          prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
1>c:\users\user\dropbox\visual studio projects\fooProj\fooProj\A.cpp(576): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\user\dropbox\visual studio projects\fooProj\fooProj\A.cpp(576): error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\user\dropbox\visual studio projects\fooProj\fooProj\A.cpp(576): error C2923: 'A' : 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'
1>c:\users\user\dropbox\visual studio projects\fooProj\fooProj\A.cpp(576): error C2923: 'A<T>::node' : 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'S'
1>c:\users\user\dropbox\visual studio projects\fooProj\fooProj\A.cpp(613): error C2509: 'foo' : member function not declared in 'A'
1>          c:\users\user\dropbox\visual studio projects\fooProj\fooProj\A.h(11) : see declaration of 'A'
1>c:\users\user\dropbox\visual studio projects\fooProj\fooProj\A.cpp(613): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

am i missing something too obvious?

edit:

```
A.h
```

```
#ifndef TEMP_H

#define TEMP_H

template <typename T>
class A {
    template <typename S>
    struct node
    {
        S value;
        struct node* right;
        struct node* left;
    };


private:
    node<T>* removeWithTwoChildren();
};

template <typename T>
A<T>::template node<T>* A<T>::removeWithTwoChildren() {
    A<T> temp = new A<T>;
    return temp;
}

#endif
```

it doesn't need to be a struct, i could use also a class.

i'm using vc++ 2013.

the place i'm having the problem is at the return type declaration

```
A<T>::template node<T>*
```

i want to return

```
node<T>*
```

Comment: @billz But `foo` is not a nested template.

Comment: Try `template <typename T> A<T>::template node<T>* A<T>::foo()` (Note the added `template` which I guess is needed since `A::node` is a dependent name, and the compiler needs to be told that it's a template in order to parse the following `<T>`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I'm stepping out on a limb to suggest this is what you likely need:

```
template<typename T>
typename A<T>::template node<T>* A<T>::foo()
{
    // your stuff goes here   
}
```

In case you're wondering where that came from [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords/613132#613132). Johannes is an absolute machine in the realm of C++ and templates, and frankly has *forgotten* more about the language than most people will ever *know*. Read that post. The issue you're experiencing comes from dependent name resolution. You need to "tell" the compiler the thing about to follow is also a template.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,it's the same, i'm new to templates, it's in two files but if i have after the declaration #import "A.hxx" gives the same error

Comment: `#import` ?? um. You mean `#include`, right ? (and templates don't go in .cpp files, the go in headers-only except *very rare* circumstances). All of this should be in *one* header. Posting *real* code would help a *lot*.

Comment: yes #include i meant, i have A.h and A.hxx. Have tried also having them in the same file, still the same thing

Comment: @Koradi post both files up in your question, separating them, and marking with a comment where precisely you're experiencing your error (and make SURE the files you post exhibit the error). Also post your compiler brand and version (gcc, vc++, clang, etc). I *think* you're using vc++, but I don't know what version or if even that is accurate. Your error indicates it is in `A.cpp`, so bring that as well.

Comment: @Koradi After reviewing your posted update, 1. There is no member called `removeWithTwoChildren` in the template class `A`. There is a member `foo`, so naturally the definition of an unknown template member out-of-class isn't going to work. After updating (including making things public for demo), [See It Live](http://ideone.com/5ybwqN)

Comment: yes i worked that out when i found the solution at microsoft's website http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0afb82ta.aspx, thank you also for your help